# how can I set leaflet map background to be white?

Tags: leaflet

I am currently using leaflet to show data, in general, it worked very well, but our PM wants the map background to be white instead of gray. Right now, the whole map is having gray background, I checked the document and can not find out solution at all about how to make the background white.
Thank you very much for your suggestions.

I saw this is caused by the tileLayer,

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + this.props.mapBoxToken, {
            //attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.light'
        })
        .addTo(this.map);
```

here, if I remove the tileLayer,  then background color can be seen. I googled a lot how to change the tilelayer color, but can not find out solution, hope to hear your advice.

Answer (score 24):

If you look at Leaflet's [CSS file carefully](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/3bc00660f4e61e1c297c9dacc607c0740818a99c/dist/leaflet.css#L247), you'll find these rules:

```
.leaflet-container {
    background: #ddd;
    outline: 0;
}
```

That's what makes the map's container background gray. Simply create another CSS rule overriding that.

e.g. if you're using `<div id='my-leaflet-map'></div>` as the map container, then something like

```
#my-leaflet-map {
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: changing background to any color is useless, it seemed the map is already having some color layer and container background color is not visible at all.

Comment: @user3006967 so you meant you want to change the "background" of your tiles, instead of the map _container_ background? You would have better explained what you mean by "background", possibly with a little sketch.

Comment: Map can contains no tile layer, only some vector layers (`L.Marker`, `L.Polyline` and so on) or, for example, `L.ImageOverlay` with transparent PNG or SVG image. In this case changing map background is useful.

Comment: `background: transparent` or `inherit` is also a good option.

Answer (score -2):

controlled by map.id of the mapbox, https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps